# How use case scenario should look like, when use case have extensions points or include something

Tags: uml, use-case

I have this simple UC diagram.
[image]

Firstly, when the customer enters a repair order, the system checks whether the order can be processed (if the repair company can repair this model of device) - UC **"Enter repair order"**. Only if company can repair this device, customer will start another UC **"Select repair type"**, in the end, depending on which repair type customer will select, it will go to **"Enter home address"** or **"Enter city"**.

My question is, if I want to build Use Case Scenario for UC **"Enter repair order"** how should it look like? Should I write in the main course, that customer can enter another use case?

i.e:

MAIN COURSE

1. Customer login to the webpage.
2. Customer fills in an order form.
3. System displays information that the company can repair this device.
4. Customer enters UC **"Select repair type"**.
5. System displays information that the order has been saved.

ALTERNATIVE COURSE

3. System displays information that the company cannot repair this device.
4. System displays information that the order has not been saved and ends use case.

Or this should be rather:

MAIN COURSE

1. Customer login to the webpage.
2. Customer fills in an order form.
3. System displays information that the company can repair this device.
4. Customer enters UC **"Select repair type"** and ends use case.

ALTERNATIVE COURSE

3. System displays information that the company cannot repair this device.
4. System displays information that the order has not been saved and ends use case.

Does this scenario make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I'd do is throw away the use case diagram. In other answers, I've frequently quoted Martin Fowler, either from [his site](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UseCase.html) or [his book, UML Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321193687), where he expresses the lack of usefulness and value in UML Use Case diagrams. I'd only look at the two textual representations of the use case.

The next step is to clearly define what a use case is. A use case is a definition for how a user interacts with software (or a system) to achieve a useful result, considering inputs and responses to those inputs (or outputs). Based on this definition, the first example of a textual representation of the use case is the better of the two, since the main course actually ends with something valuable happening.

I'm not a fan of the extraction into child use cases, though, at least based on this example. It may make sense to promote reuse of the detailed textual descriptions, but unless the same steps related to "select repair type", "enter home address" and "enter city" are reused in several use cases, I would consider those steps in the "enter repair order" use case. I'd also question why "enter home address" and "enter city" are separate use cases, since a city is a part of an address. It seems like there are more detailed design decisions being made here regarding how the domain is being modeled that wouldn't be appropriate for consideration at the use case level.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, there is a reason why I put those use cases separately. Users will have some unique interactions with each of them. What do you think about the two scenarios which I've shared? Which one is better?

Comment: @HubertKaczmarczyk As I said, the first textual representation is better, but it still has some problems. The numbering doesn't work well (although the numbering system in markdown here is limited) - normally, you'd use multiple levels of numbering (3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 4.1, 4.2 for example) to denote the steps in each alternate flow rather than a single sequence of numbers. Without seeing more use cases, I can't speak to the "goodness" of splitting out the "select repair type" or the other use cases, but it does seem premature.

Comment: Your answer along with this topic helped me to get the gist and go forward - https://www.sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php?topic=26266.0.